# Why can't bcp execute procedures having temp table(#tempTable)?

Tags: stored-procedures, bcp, sql-server-2008, sql-agent-job

Recently I was tasked with creating a SQL Server Job to automate the creation of a CSV file. There was existing code, which was using an assortment of #temp tables.

When I set up the job to execute using BCP calling the existing code (converted into a procedure), I kept getting errors:

```
SQLState = S0002, NativeError = 208
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Invalid object name #xyz
```

As described in other post(s), to resolve the problem lots of people recommend converting all the #tempTables to @tableVariables.

However, I would like to understand WHY BCP doesn't seem to be able to use #tempTables? 
When I execute the same procedure from within SSMS it works though!? Why?

I did do a quick and simple test using global temp tables within a procedure and that seemed to succeed via a job using BCP, so I am assuming it is related to the scope of the #tempTables!?

Thanks in advance for your responses/clarifications.

DTML

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in guessing that it's a scope issue for the #temp tables.

BCP is spawned as a separate process, so the tables are no longer in scope for the new processes.  SSMS likely uses sub-processes, so they would still have access to the #temp tables.